# Joining the min value in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Consider this code:

```
var list = from n in Personal
           join b in SeekerProfileImage on n.Seek_Per_ID equals b.Seek_Per_ID
            into a
           from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()

           join c in Resume on n.Seek_Per_ID equals c.Seek_Per_ID
           join d in Education on c.Seek_Resume_ID.Min() equals d.Seek_Resume_ID
           where ( Convert.ToBoolean((c.Seek_Resume_ID).Min()))
           select new
           {
               firtname=n.FirstName,
               secondname=n.LastName,
               university = d.Univ_Name,
               perid = n.Seek_Per_ID,
               filename = b.ImageType,
               imagetype = (b == null ? "http://localhost:10057/JobSearch/images/advertisment/head-silhouette.png" : "http://localhost:10057/JobSearch/images/SeekerIMG/" + n.Seek_Per_ID + "." + b.ImageType)
              // imagetype = (b == null ? Server.MapPath("~images/advertisment/head-silhouette.png") : b.ImageType)
           };
```

I want to join resume and education, but only for the minimum resumeid for each employee. How can I do it? The above is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your collection of Resume into a collection of one resume per EmployeeID, you can apply the below expression to Resume. This groups the resume's by EmployeeID, orders each group by ResumeID, and then selects the first of each of the ordered groups.

```
Resume.GroupBy(r => r.EmployeeID).Select(gr => gr.OrderBy(r => r.ResumeID).First());
```

Comment: i want to order by minimum resume id is it possible , thank you